# powercenter SQL override query order by

Tags: sql, informatica-powercenter

I have a lookup SQL override in which i want to achieve an order between the union queries, such that first row in results come from the first query, second row comes from the second query and third row comes from the third query. Another scenario is that If there are no results from first and second query then i get third row in results on top etc. I want to use as a constant in each query and use order by at the end to achieve this result, since there is no field in my query which I can do an order by on.

```
Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_dept, 1 as rank 
from employee

union

Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_dept, 2 as rank 
from employee

union

Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_dept, 3 as rank 

from employee
order by rank
```

This runs fine in DB2 but gives function sequence error in power center lookup SQL override. I have tried creating a rank port in lookup but nothing resolves the issue. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_dept, rank from (
Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_dept, 1 as rank 
from employee

union

Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_dept, 2 as rank 
from employee

union

Select emp_id,emp_name,emp_dept, 3 as rank 

from employee)
order by rank
```

Basically, you are combining all data sets and sorting afterwards.